# SAP ABAP write long JSON String as variable or Literal without big formatting

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, abap

is it somehow possible to write long JSON data in ABAP as string literal without doing a lot of line breaks or formatting of the string? e.g could I enclose the string in some kind of string template or so? or does there exists a method like JSON.stringify(..) somewhere in ABAP? Or maybe it works with includes? I have no idea and I'm still quite new to ABAP...

e.g this data:

```
{"todos":[{"id":1,"todo":"Do something nice for someone I care about","completed":true,"userId":26},{"id":2,"todo":"Memorize the fifty states and their capitals","completed":false,"userId":48},{"id":3,"todo":"Watch a classic movie","completed":false,"userId":4},{"id":4,"todo":"Contribute code or a monetary donation to an open-source software project","completed":false,"userId":48},{"id":5,"todo":"Solve a Rubik's cube","completed":false,"userId":31},{"id":6,"todo":"Bake pastries for me and neighbor","completed":false,"userId":39},{"id":7,"todo":"Go see a Broadway production","completed":false,"userId":32},{"id":8,"todo":"Write a thank you letter to an influential person in my life","completed":true,"userId":13},{"id":9,"todo":"Invite some friends over for a game night","completed":false,"userId":47},{"id":10,"todo":"Have a football scrimmage with some friends","completed":false,"userId":19},{"id":11,"todo":"Text a friend I haven't talked to in a long time","completed":false,"userId":39},{"id":12,"todo":"Organize pantry","completed":true,"userId":39},{"id":13,"todo":"Buy a new house decoration","completed":false,"userId":16},{"id":14,"todo":"Plan a vacation I've always wanted to take","completed":false,"userId":28},{"id":15,"todo":"Clean out car","completed":false,"userId":33},{"id":16,"todo":"Draw and color a Mandala","completed":true,"userId":24},{"id":17,"todo":"Create a cookbook with favorite recipes","completed":false,"userId":1},{"id":18,"todo":"Bake a pie with some friends","completed":false,"userId":1},{"id":19,"todo":"Create a compost pile","completed":true,"userId":5}]}
```

It would be the ideal thing if there exists something like template string literals in ABAP like `` in javascript where you then can include ' and " without escaping characters...

btw... I want to deserialize the JSON into an internal Table and then insert it into my Dictionary Table with a loop which already seemed to work,

```
DATA: lv_json TYPE string VALUE '[{"id":10,"todo": ...}]'
```

I just don't know yet how to find a good format to parse the JSON... (does there also exist a program to parse json from file?)..

Comment: thanks, but I rather would like to find out how to write long JSON strings as literals in abap code

Comment: No, but with Eclipse ADT type or paste it directly (it will go on one line) and save, it will split automatically on several lines by adding `&&` (which doesn't work with `DATA ... VALUE ...`, with `&&` you have to use a simple assignment or expression).

Comment: @SandraRossi thanks it actually worked after I assigned it to a variable. I enclosed the string in `` and eclipse did what you said.

Comment: String templates exist with |string|. Most performant (de)serialization is with Simple Transformations. Not so performant are the build in classes

Comment: Is there a good reason why you **must** do that via JSON? If this is just to hardcode some complex data-structure, there are VALUE literals for tables and structures you could use.

Comment: `without doing a lot of line breaks or formatting of the string` when saving to string ABAP does not do any formatting or string breaking, and JSON is not an exclusion. It will be written as is by default. So you don't need to do nothing, you question has no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While ABAP doesn't have a syntax for multi-line string literals, you can concatenate strings via `&&`. When you have both `{` and `'` in your code, then you can still use the ` -character which gives you a `string` literal without parsing any string templates:

```
DATA(lv_json_string) = 
  `{"todos":[` &&
  `{"id":1,"todo":"Do something nice for someone I care about","completed":true,"userId":26},` &&
  `{"id":2,"todo":"Memorize the fifty states and their capitals","completed":false,"userId":48},` &&
  `{"id":3,"todo":"Watch a classic movie","completed":false,"userId":4}` &&
  `]}`.
```

You can then parse this string with the class `cl_abap_json`.

However, if the whole purpose of this string is to hard-code some content for an internal table, then there is a much better way to accomplish this: By using [a `VALUE` literal](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_755_index_htm/7.55/en-US/index.htm?file=abenvalue_constructor_params_itab.htm). Assuming the table type you defined in the dictionary is called `z_todo_table`, you could do this:

```
DATA(lt_my_table) = VALUE z_todo_table(
   ( id = 1 todo = `Do something nice for someone I care about` completed = abap_true userId = 26 )
   ( id = 2 todo = `Memorize the fifty states and their capitals` completed = abap_false userId = 48 )
   ( id = 3 todo = `Watch a classic movie` completed = abap_false userId = 4 )
).
```

This is probably not only a lot faster and simpler than using a JSON parser, it also will catch formatting errors at activation time and not only at runtime.

Comment: thanks for the input, the thing is just, json is pretty omnipresent these days and I sometimes have quite big datasets of json e.g from a file, I still don't know how to parse a json file into a table... But in eclipse it works well with ` and && because it does it automatically...  the value literal is also nice but I would have to parse the json in some other way and rewrite them into value literals...

Comment: @Marc_L You wrote in your question *"I want to deserialize the JSON into an internal Table and then insert it into my Dictionary Table with a loop **which already seemed to work**"*, which lead me to believe that you already had a solution for reading data from a JSON string. Perhaps you might want to post a new question that explicitly asks about how to parse JSON in ABAP and not on how to write long string literals.

Comment: @Marc_L Or perhaps your question is how to read data from a file in the first place? That's also something you might want to ask as a new question. If you do, please tell us if you are talking about a file on the server or a file on the client, because those are handled very differently in ABAP.

Comment: yes indeed that would be interesting to know ;)